# Creating Single Flask executable file with Pyinstaller

Tags: python, flask, executable

I have created a flask application which runs on a local server. I need to turn it into a single executable file using pyinstaller.

The following is my directory structure for my flask application in PyCharm:

```
Form
- migrations
- venv
- - app
- - - static
- - - templates
- - - __init__.py
- - - forms.py
- - - models.py
- - - routes.py
- microform.py
- config.py
- app.db
```

I tried running

```
pyinstaller -w -F --add-data "C:\Users\test\PycharmProjects\Form\venv\app\templates;templates" 
--add-data "C:\Users\test\PycharmProjects\Form\venv\app\static;static" 
--add-data "C:\Users\test\PycharmProjects\Form\migrations;migrations" microform.py
```

Everything compiled properly, and the flask application works except for the database that I created. I am unable to login because but the flask application gives me the following error when I input my username and password:

```
sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (sqlite3.OperationalError) unable to open database file
(Background on this error at: http://sqlalche.me/e/e3q8)
```

Everything works fine when I run it in PyCharm, but when I try opening it by clicking on the executable file from pyinstaller it just gives me the above error whenever I try to login?

Appreciate any help or advice. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You should run the pyinstaller command with your main file, where you call all of your functions and classes.

You might check the following link:

https://datatofish.com/executable-pyinstaller/

Comment: I guess your paths are not correct. I never used pyinstaller, but apparently pyinstaller tries to access 'C:\Users\test\PycharmProjects\Form\templates', and it doesn't exist. Be sure that you assign all the paths correct in the arguments.